# Invoke method in stored object

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm a bit confused atm and i dont think it could be this hard as then i must be doing something wrong. What i am trying to do now for the past 2 days is to access a method inside an object that is stored in an List and i just cant get at it. In my mind it should just be to get the object back to its originated type and invoke the method but i just cant do it.

I been reading alot about Type, Generics and reflection but it cant get anyting to work so i am obviusly doing it all wrong and i need help finding the light!

Heres the latest code i have tried

```
            Object customer = Hotel.Main.Manager.GetMainList(x);
            Type frsttype = customer.GetType();              
            MethodInfo method = frsttype.GetMethod("GetCustomerSpecificData");
            MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(frsttype);
            String str = generic.Invoke(method);
```

What i am trying to reach is this method inside the object:

```
            public override string GetCustomerSpecificData()
    {
        string strout = string.Format("{0,-5}{1,26}{2,28}{3,28}\a", ID, Name, Age, Gender);

        string strInfo = Extra;
        strout += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strInfo) ? string.Empty : strInfo);

        if (m_specialoffer)
        {
            strout += string.Format("\nSpecial Offer");
        }
        if (IsRegularCustomer)
        {
            strout += (IsDangerus ? "\nIs a regular customer " : "\nIs not a regular customer.");
        }
        strout += Environment.NewLine + PaymentInfo();
        strout += (m_CarPark ? "\nHas car parked in garage." : "\nDoes not have car parked in garage.");
        return strout;
    }
```

I hope someone can point me in the correct direction as i dont think i am getting anywhere with this one :/

Any help and hints will be greatly appreciated!!! All will be upvoted for replies!

Regards

Comment: Why do you have to go this route? Can't you simply cast to Customer and then call the method? `((Customer) customer).GetCustomerSpecificData();`

Comment: Sorry, i was unclear. The object can be a few different types that i have declared in an enum, the object is created depending on wich type is is and then stored as an object. I need to be able go convert it back to orginal type not knowing before wich it was. But your idea should be alot easier then mine aslong as i can cast it to the type is was.

Comment: If you're not certain of the returned type but all of them implement this method, could you use an interface and/or base class.

Comment: Type DynamicType = typeof(Hotel.Main.CustomerObjectTypes); Should this not be helpful?  I can get the type with the line Type frsttype = customer.GetType(); so i know i can get that one, problem seems to be how to get the object back into that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest to what you currently have this could work without relying on reflection.

```
Object customer = Hotel.Main.Manager.GetMainList(x);

string result="";
var custObj = customer as Customer;
if (custObj !=null)
{
    result = custObj.GetCustomerSpecificData();
}

var specialcustObj = customer as SpecialCustomer;
if (specialcustObj !=null)
{
   result = specialcustObj.GetCustomerSpecificData();
}

/* etc */
```

Or, If you can change the implementation of the different types in the List have an interface (or alternative an (abstract) base class.

```
/* alternatively name it ISpecificData if you want adhere common used standards */
public interface SpecificData
{
     string GetCustomerSpecificData();
}
```

and for your Customer and other classes that can be in the list :

```
public class Customer:SpecificData
{
   /* rest of implemementastion stays the same */
}
```

Your code to Get a customer would go like this, and will work for every object in the list that implemented the interface.

```
Object customer = Hotel.Main.Manager.GetMainList(x);

string result="";
var interfaceObj = customer as SpecificData;
if (interfaceObj != null) 
{
  result = interfaceObj.GetCustomerSpecificData();
}
```

When you know that only a specific interface will be in the list you can use the generic list to only hold object for that specific type:

```
mainlist = new List<SpecificData>();
```

and you can adapt GetMainList to only return the interface SpecificData

Comment: Thanks Rene!!! You saved me! I allready had the class heraki as u mentiond with an interface<-abstract<-public class so it was very easy just adding the contract in the interface and go that way. It just jumped to life and im over the moon!! Thanks a million for your time!!! Have a great day!

Comment: Only a minor comment here in that I was always taught it was convention/good practice to name interfaces beginning with "I" - presumably to make code easier to read and thus more maintainable. This is a pattern I have seen repeated in a number of C# books. In the example above the interface "SpecificData" would therefore be named "ISpecificData". I only mention this in case it helps someone reading the question who hasn't experience of working with inferfaces before.

Comment: In the debate to get rid of the hungarian notation and have our IDE's infer types under our fingertips I decided to spare some key strokes...the I for interfaces is still among us, so be it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

There a few things here that you need to do, firstly lets look at the codeyou posted

First question you need t ask youself is Do I need to use reflection, can I instead use interfaces or return a type that I know?

Do you have control of the GetMainList(x)? If so cant you change it so it returns something more useful other then a object?

```
Object customer = Hotel.Main.Manager.GetMainList(x);
```

Can you cast to anything?

Secondly your target method is no a generic method so the line below is not going to work.

```
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(frsttype);
```

You are also invoking the method incorrectly you Invoke has two arguments the first one is the target object you wish to invoke the method against and the parameters you can pass into it.

```
Invoke(object obj, object[] parameters)
```

To invoke you method you need to the following.

```
Object customer = Hotel.Main.Manager.GetMainList(x);
Type frsttype = customer.GetType();
MethodInfo method = frsttype.GetMethod("GetCustomerSpecificData");
String str = method.Invoke(customer, null) as string;
```

There is some great questions and community wikis on stackoverflow and of course there is many tutorials and example in the MSDN library.

A nice tutorial for reflection in .net can be found below.

- [Reflection in C# Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial)

Answer (score 3):

i mean you can easy invoke it  :

```
 Type myType =customer.GetType();
 MethodInfo method = typeof(customer).GetMethod("GetCustomerSpecificData");
 MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(myType);
 var res= generic.Invoke(this, null);
```